# How to access Domain class in src/main/java in Grails 3.3.11?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, import, grails3

My domain class has two values name1 and name2. I able to set name1 using UI.I want set name2 by using a service which will call a method of a java class. i.e src/main/java

when i run the application , i am getting this error "package trygroovyandjava does not exist"

//Domain class

```
package trygroovyandjava

class Name {
String name1
    String name2
    static constraints = {
        name1 nullable: false
        name2 nullable: true
    }
}
```

//service

```
package trygroovyandjava

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Transactional
class SetName2Service {

    def serviceMethod(Name name) {
        setname.Name2.setNames(name)

    }
}
```

//java class

```
package setname;
import trygroovyandjava.Name;
public class Name2 {
    public static void setNames(Name name){
        String name2="vishal";
        name.setName2(name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @EugeneHoza package name

Comment: I have the solution  add this code in build.gradle or just add all your java classes in src/main/groovy `sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDirs = [] }
        groovy { srcDirs += ['src/main/java'] }
    }
}`

Comment: In a Grails app common convention is to put the Java and Groovy source under `src/main/groovy/` and if you do that, you don't have to deviate from the default Gradle config.  If you want to keep them in separate directories for some reason, then configuring the `srcDirs` will let you do that, as you found.

Comment: The same convention applies for any Gradle project which mixes Groovy and Java source code, not just Grails apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution, add this code in build.gradle or just add all your java classes in 
src/main/groovy

```
sourceSets { main { java { srcDirs = [] } groovy { srcDirs += ['src/main/java'] } } }
```